# Коммутация трафика к разным серверам

Tags: linux, c, сеть, kernel

Пишу балансировщик нагрузки сети, возник вопрос по поводу работы сети в целом.

Есть два коммутатора, сервер балансировки, клиенты и серверы (допустим, что все серверы идентичны).

Подключено это следующим образом: клиенты подключены к первому коммутатору, сервер балансировки подключен и к первому и ко второму коммутатору (две сетевые карты), серверы подключены ко второму коммутатору.

Сервер балансировки, имея данные о загруженности серверов, изменяет адрес назначения пакета от клиента, пересчитывает контрольную сумму, и отправляет в интерфейс, который смотрит в сторону серверов (второй коммутатор).

Изначально я хотел обрабатывать весь трафик, проходящий к/через сервер балансировки, но после тестов понял, что не хватит мощности сервера для такой работы.

Вопросы:

1. Возможно ли такое: клиент обращается к серверу балансировки, к примеру обычный tcp-клиент, я изменяю адрес назначения на свободный сервер, далее клиент, получив ответ от сервера, уже общается с сервером напрямую. (я не уверен что так будет работать).
2. Как ещё можно заставить клиента общаться напрямую с нужным мне сервером?

Comment: Боюсь только средствами протоколов высокого уровня, например выдавать redirect протокола HTTP. Или еще до запросов решать вопросы балансировки несколькими IP для одной DNS записи, тогда DNS сама все сделает, т.к. отдает адреса в случайном порядке. Ну или железными средствами коммутатора. А с помощью своего балансировщика для произвольных протоколов - только обрабатывая весь поток

Comment: Вопрос может не совсем в тему, но всё же: а почему не HAProxy?

Comment: @donRumata Нужно своё ПО разработать

Comment: Вопрос, у вас не хватает мощностей на обработку чего именно? Вы каждый пакет передаёте на своё приложение-балансировщик, где (возможно даже в userspace) осуществляете модификацию пакета? Или приложение получает только неизвестные пакеты, затем заносит это соединение в conntrack и дальнейшие пакеты обрабатывает ядро в kernel mode? Вопрос второй: трафика больше к серверу или от него? Исходящему трафику можно изменять src сразу на серверах и заворачивать на какой-нибудь отдельный более глупый роутер, тогда банасировщик должен обрабатывать только пакеты входящего трафика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, можно отослать клиенту [icmp-пакет redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Redirect) с кодом 1 — *redirect for host*.